# Can electromagnetic radiation be half-wave rectified in free space?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

[image: Wave Profile Comparison]

Electric field strength vs propagation direction of electromagnetic radiation(Wave Profile Comparison)

Comment: What can be rectified (using matter) is a potential difference, it's not the electric field itself.

Comment: Please elaborate what the question here is - the half-wave rectified version is probably not a vacuum solution to Maxwell's equation, so it can't exist in free space. Also, don't ask the question only in the title, also have the question in the body of the post.

Comment: It seems clear to me what is being asked so I don't understand the close as unclear votes. The question is whether a propagating EM wave with the form shown in the second diagram can exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to get an answer in quickly because your question is on the cusp of being closed. So I'll answer briefly then revisit this answer when I have time.

The solution to the Maxwell's equations in a vacuum is a plane wave, and any combination of plane waves is also a solution. So you can take an arbitrary waveform like the one you propose and Fourier analyse it to express it as a sum of plane waves. The to produce your waveform just combine the plane waves.

So yes, you can produce the waveform you describe, though I have one reservation that I need time to think about. For a waveform like yours that does not integrate to zero over a cycle the Fourier series would need a constant term. I don't think this is a problem, but I would need to sit down and think about to be sure.

Comment: Solutions of Maxwell equations are not restricted to plane waves. It is not correct to claim "plane wave is the solution". Also, the waveform in the question already refers to plane wave - the electric strength is a function of only one coordinate. Any waveform $E(x)$ for plane wave is valid if the only condition is that it obeys Maxwell's equations in vacuum. This is because  for any $E(x)$ the function $E(x-ct)$ obeys the wave equation.

Comment: @JánLalinský: thanks Ján, but since plane waves are solutions, and any periodic wave can be Fourier analysed into plane waves, my argument still holds does it not?

Comment: Any function $E(x)$ describes profile of a plane wave that can exist and propagate. This can be shown directly from the wave equation - there is no need for Fourier analysis.